# Certain colors not showing on Cycles Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texture-painting

I was recently working on a character model, and I encountered a problem while using the Texture Paint mode.
I unwrapped and assigned a texture to every piece of the model, and then went to the Texture Paint mode to work on it. When I finished the work I rendered it to check the result, and then I noticed certain colors of the texture didn't appear at all in the render.
The flat texture and the model in 3D view look like this:
[image]

Whereas the render looks like this:
[image]

For further reference, I'm using Cycles Render, and used the node editor to apply several shadings and displacement.
For the scene, I'm using two spotlights, both white in color, and black background.
Also, while in Texture Paint, I used the Multiply and Lighten blends for adding contrast, and the Overlay blend for applying the purple hue.
I'm using Blender 2.74.

Here is my node setup

[image]

Comment: If you have painted and saved the texture and that contains the purple color, I think that the problem can't be due to something you have done in texture painting. If the texture looks good, it is more likely that is your node setup that leads to the BW result. Could you post it? Or uplad a file?

Comment: Please show your material nodes in the node editor, this will help others to understand the situation.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/3puxgkyf5/  Here's the node setup, the image texture is on the upper left. The two other images are used for displacement and reflection, they're both on a grayscale.

Comment: It would be helpful to others to post your node image in the question.  Not the comment.

Comment: I know, but since it's my first time here, I can't upload more than 2 images on the same post, apparently.

Comment: Fortunately someone has graciously extended a forum courtesy.  Sometimes you can take two separate images and combine them. Such as the first two images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a mathematical multiply. You should be using an RGB multiply [image]

You can get the color multiply in the add menu <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>>*Color*>*MixRGB* and set the drop down the multiply.

The reason the math multiply doesn't work is that it simply multiplies a *single* value (per pixel) together, giving one output channel. The Color multiply multiplies each of the three channels (per pixel) and gives a three channel output.

This is how a multiply RGB node works, using the mathematical multiply:

[image]

Each color channel on the first image is multiplied by the corrosponding one on the second image. They are then added together to make a new image.

The factor merely mixes the multiplied image with the un-affected image.

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much for your swift response.

Comment: @RobertoGarcíaPeñuelas If you found this post helpful, please mark it as accepted via the checkmark next to the vote buttons.

Comment: Isn't it 4 channels?

Comment: @someonewithpc Depends whether or not the image has alpha. I'm not sure if the alphas are multiplied in blender (but don't think so), and have no place to check.